# how to sort a dict by keys and values at the same time? in fact, in my dict, keys are strings and i want to sort alphabetically and values are number

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, key

I want to sort the dict below by values firstly from max to min and when two values have the same amount, I want to sort it alphabetically?
my problem:

```
the_dict={ 'Action': 3, 'Romance':2, 'Adventure':1 , 'Comedy': 2 , 'History'=1, 'Horror'=3}
```

I have used:

```
for key, value in sorted(dict.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda x:(x[1], x[0])):
     print(key,':',value)
```

I have gotten the result below:

```
'Action': 3
'Horror':3
'Comedy': 2
'Romance':2
'History':1
'Adventure':1
```

but my idea result is:

```
'Action': 3
'Horror':3
'Comedy': 2
'Romance':2
'Adventure':1
'History':1
```

How can I reach my favorite result?

Comment: they are not the same, in my gotten result, 'History':1 comes before 'Adventure':1. but I want to firstly get  'Adventure':1 then 'History':1. In fact, alphabetically sorted.

Answer (score 0):

As your values are int, you can do something like this:

```
for key, value in sorted(the_dict.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])):
    print(key, ':', value)
```